# How to fix </item> tag problem inside value.xml?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to update my old android application but I could not solve this error.

`.../app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:815: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.`
`.../app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:816: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.`
`.../app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:817: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.`

1: I have tried to delete the build folder inside app and build it again but get the same error.

2: I change the format as `<item type="id" name="id_name" />` but again when I try to build again the error comes again with the old format and error.

**gradle app: **
`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'yagmur.lyrics'
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 2
    versionName 'Pro'

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        zipAlignEnabled true

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
}
productFlavors {
}
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven {
    url "https://jitpack.io"
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation files('libs/jsoup.jar')
implementation 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.lapism:searchview:4.0'


implementation 'com.gjiazhe:PanoramaImageView:1.0'
implementation project(path: ':play_widget')
}
```

`
**gradle app_widget**

`
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 2
    versionName "2.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard- 
android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
resourcePrefix "pw_"

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
}
```

`

Comment: Errors says that some of your values at xml resources are not properly formatted.

Comment: bro go to the file don't change on the file which is open automatically just go to your file edit there

Comment: Are you using any library project ?

Comment: Please upload your xml code

Comment: Tried to change format and build again but same error

Answer (score 0):

first, upgrade your build version

```
buildToolsVersion
```

then change the below three things in your gradle file

```
  compileSdkVersion 'your api level'
  minSdkVersion 'your api level'
  targetSdkVersion 'your api level'
```

also upgrade this dependency

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:'your api level''
}
```

Comment: Can you please check gradle files that added minutes ago?

Comment: Are you asking about version ?

Comment: Yes. This is the changed version but again same error when try to build signed apk.

Comment: Okay, Try moving your project to Android X, Goto Refractor>Migrate to Android X